# Capture values ​in array in C

Tags: c

At this location, I wanted to put the coordinate values ​​given in the text into an array, but after throwing them, the code continues to throw other numbers. Where is my mistake in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char metin[] = "1B(5,5)(13,12)(8,17)(1,10)(5,5)F";
    int koordinatlar[10];
    
    char *ptr = metin;
    int i = 0;
    
    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if(*ptr == '(')
        {
            int x, y;
            if(sscanf(ptr, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2)
            {
                koordinatlar[i] = x;
                koordinatlar[i + 1] = y;
                i += 2;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr++;
        }
    }
    
    int a = 0;
    
    while(koordinatlar[a] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%d ", koordinatlar[a]);
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you find a `(%d,%d)` you advance `ptr` by `1` ... but `(%d,%d)` is `5` or more bytes!! Hint: `scanf()` has the `"%n"` conversion that may help you.

Comment: Your final loop checks for `koordinatlar[a] != '\0'` but you were putting ints in, and I don't see where you might add a 0

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong loop termination**

There is no place where `koordinatlar[i]` was assigned a zero.
Rather than iterate until `koordinatlar[a] != '\0'`, loop until the last populated `int koordinatlar[]` was assigned.  Use `i`.

```
// int a = 0;
// while(koordinatlar[a] != '\0'

for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
  printf("%d ", koordinatlar[a]);
}
```